# Exchange 2013: Get-SenderIdConfig

Tags: exchange-2013

I am running Exchange 2013, and need to take some actions for blocking spam. 
While checking i performed Get-SenderIdConfig

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-SenderIdConfig    
    RunspaceId            : 7b21e717-eee2-42fc-9675-68be92eb4804
    SpoofedDomainAction   : Delete
    TempErrorAction       : StampStatus
    BypassedRecipients    : {a,b,c,d}
    BypassedSenderDomains : {x,y,z}
    Name                  : SenderIdConfig
    Enabled               : False
    ExternalMailEnabled   : True
    InternalMailEnabled   : False
```

My Main question is about last 3 lines,

Enabled : False

ExternalMailEnabled   : True

InternalMailEnabled   : False

Question: is SenderID config enabled or not. 
I can see that it is not enabled, but for external emails it is enabled, or should it be enabled first so that ExternalMail and internalMail take effect.

Additional Information Sender ID Agents are enabled:

```
Sender Id Agent                                    True            6
Sender Filter Agent                                True            7
```

Please advise.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

***Enabled*** -> specifies whether the Sender ID agent is enabled on the computer on which you're running the command.

***ExternalMailEnabled*** -> specifies whether all messages from unauthenticated connections external to your organization are passed
   through the Sender ID agent for processing.

***InternalMailEnabled*** -> specifies whether all messages from authenticated sender domains that belong to authoritative domains in
   your enterprise are passed through the Sender ID agent for
   processing.

So if the ***Enabled*** is set to false, none of the ***ExternalMailEnabled*** setting or ***InternalMailEnabled*** setting works.